# Visual Studio Code - Open new window instead of new tab during debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there a way to for VS Code to open a new window in Chrome instead of using existing Chrome window and opening a new tab? (I want each debug session to start off with a clean HttpContext.Session).

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Development",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net7.0/Nexgen.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",                              
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    },
    "launchSettingsProfile": "Development"
}
```

I've tried the following, without any success:

1. Adding a `"args": [ "--new-window" ]` setting to my `launch.json` file.
2. Adding a new task to 'startChrome' and calling it and 'build'.  It did launch a new Chrome window, but the debugger still attached to/launched in the previously running browser.

```
{
    "label": "startChrome",
    "type": "process",
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    "args": [
        "--new-window",
        "http://localhost:5000"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

3. Adding a `"commandLineArgs": "--new-instance http://localhost:7058",` to my `launchSettings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by setting `serverReadyAction.action = debugWithChrome` in launch.json.